# Same page and multicols

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I use multicols at times for specific blocks in my thesis, which has a title, and a block of stuff similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{mh}[1]{%
    \textbf{#1}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
}{%BODY
    \end{multicols}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mh}{This is the title.}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{mh}
\end{document}
```

[image: Top]

I am getting an occurrence which is creating a page break between the title and the body, so I need to be able to instruct them to be on the same page. However the problem is, that using `begin{samepage} ... \end{samepage}` destroys the `multicols` environment, putting all the text in one column as per below:

```
 %NEED TO FORCE HEADING AND BLOCK ON SAME PAGE
 \begin{samepage}
    \begin{mh}{This is the title.}
         \lipsum[1]
    \end{mh}
\end{samepage}
```

[image: Bottom]

Anyone know how to work this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way: use the optional argument that the `{multicols}` environment has for exactly such purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{mh}[1]{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\textbf{#1}]%
}{%BODY
 \end{multicols}%
}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{.89\textheight}% this page
% \vspace*{.90\textheight}% next page

\begin{mh}{This is the title.}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mh}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, definitely simpler... I blame David for teaching me to _not_ read documentation. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill :) I didn't read it either - I simply happened to remember the optional argument...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the `needspace` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace) to add a new page if there is not enough space for both the title and the content.

### Note:

- It would be better to provide MWE that actually reproduces the problem (as the one below does if you comment out the `\needspace{3\baselineskip}`.
- The MWE below will keep three lines together on the page, otherwise will go to a new page. If you prefer to keep a few more lines with the section heading you can increase the factor `3` to a larger number.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{mh}[1]{%
    \needspace{3\baselineskip}%
    \textbf{#1}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
}{%BODY
    \end{multicols}%
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \begin{mh}{This is the title.}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{mh}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a minipage environment instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{mh}[1]{%
    \textbf{#1}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
}{%BODY
    \end{multicols}%
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{mh}{This is the title.}
         \lipsum[1]
    \end{mh}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But it spoils indentation.