# How to extend the columnseprule on the final page of a multicol environment?

Tags: multicol, rules

On the final page of a two-column portion of a text that uses `multicol`, I want to put a one-column notice at the bottom of the page, and I'd like the rule separating the columns to extend all the way until just above the one-column portion. Using `vfill` outside `multicols` puts the notice in the right place but the rule only extends as far as the actual multi-column text. Using `vfill` inside `multicols` has no effect.

I'd like it to produce something like the following, but obviously without the manual `\vspace*` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
    \columnbreak
    \lipsum[2]
    \vspace*{300pt}
\end{multicols}
\centering\Huge\textbf{\textsf{STOP}}

\end{document}
```

In some respects, this is the opposite problem of the [Same page and multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114716/same-page-and-multicols?rq=1) question, in that I need to ensure that something which comes after the `multicols` environment is kept on the same page.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356306/multicols-with-one-column-content-vfill-in-multicols

Comment: That's the general idea, but I'd prefer to do that in a regular `multicol` environment, as I normally want to balance the columns, even if the MWE implies otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but even with `multicols*`, these solutions don't work when the environment goes over a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the vertical rule on the last page using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,eso-pic,lipsum,xcolor}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \sloppy\lipsum[1-15]
\end{multicols}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily STOP}}% Set STOP
    % Move to the right of the left text column
    \hspace*{.5\dimexpr\textwidth-\columnseprule-2\columnsep}%
    % Skip over column sep
    \hspace*{\columnsep}%
    % Insert vertical rule
    \rule[3\baselineskip]{\columnseprule}{\dimexpr\textheight-3\baselineskip}%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

The above example overlays a `\rule` on the final page `3\baselineskip` from the bottom of the text block overtop of whatever is on the final page.

You could add this to `\AtEndDocument`. However, there is no testing done to see whether **STOP** will fit on the page or not, and not overlay with the existing text in the columns.

---

The following example sets the **STOP** content inside a box (called `\stopbox`) and uses this box as a measure of how far the vertical rule should go down to on the last page (+ one `\baselineskip`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,eso-pic,lipsum,xcolor}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\newsavebox{\stopbox}
\savebox{\stopbox}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \Huge\bfseries\sffamily STOP \\
    \small\itshape \ldots right here
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \sloppy\lipsum[1-15]
\end{multicols}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\usebox{\stopbox}}}% Set STOP
    % Move to the right of the left text column
    \hspace*{.5\dimexpr\textwidth-\columnseprule-2\columnsep}%
    % Skip over column sep
    \hspace*{\columnsep}%
    % Insert vertical rule
    \rule[\dimexpr\ht\stopbox+\baselineskip]{\columnseprule}{\dimexpr\textheight-\ht\stopbox-\baselineskip}%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That does exactly what the MWE requested, so I'm inclined to accept this answer, but in my actual document, the "STOP" text can actually be multi-line. It has a fixed height for an individual document, so it can be precalculated, but depending on the specific document, the text can vary, so I can't hard-code a particular multiple of baseline skip. I'm not sure if I should start a new question for that point or extend this one.

Comment: @KarlHagen: By "the text can vary", are you referring to the STOP phrase, or the actual document text?

Comment: I meant the STOP phrase.

Comment: @KarlHagen: That's fine. One can define the STOP phrase in the preamble (by placing it inside a box, which makes it measurable) and use that to identify the spacing at the end of the text. I'll update my answer to provide such an option.

Comment: @KarlHagen: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The new package `multicolrule` (version 1.1) can handle this problem without the need for `eso-pic`. While Werner's solution was perfectly serviceable for the problem as set out in the MWE, in production documents it required complicated bookkeeping to deal with situations such as having one-column material above the `multicols` environment, and the original and redrawn rules were slightly misaligned, requiring me to erase the old line before redrawing it. With the new package, these issues don't arise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicolrule}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}

\newsavebox{\stopbox}
\savebox{\stopbox}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \Huge\bfseries\sffamily STOP \\
    \small\itshape \ldots right here
  \end{tabular}
}

\SetMCRule{width=0.5pt,line-style=solid,extend-fill,extend-reserve=\ht\stopbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}
\centering\usebox{\stopbox}  
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]